# Required Validations for Special Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, regex, active-directory

We have a user creation functionality in our ASP.NET application. This will create an entry in the database for the new user as well as create a new account in Active Directory. All the existing users can be searched using another functionality in the application.

At present only English alphabets and numbers are allowed to enter for user creation. However, the client wants to enter special characters also. When we tried we found following tow issues.

1)  When a user is created with only special characters, it is throwing error

2)  When searched by entering % (to see only users having @ in name), all the users are returned.

Can you please list out other possible issues so that we can form the required validations (like % should not be allowed).

Note: Anything other than “English alphabets and numbers” are considered as special character.

```
DECLARE @CharacterVal VARCHAR(10)
SET @CharacterVal = '%'

SELECT * FROM USerDetails WHERE First_Name LIKE @CharacterVal
```

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far Active-Directory is concerned [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx) discribed that caracters that are not allowed in logon name are:

" / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this via a blacklist if you're serious about security. Get a list of characters that the client wants, then whitelist only those.

Comment: If you can provide what are the safely allowed special characters, we can suggest that to the client.

Comment: Get a list from the client, try them all, report back on ones that aren't allowed.

Comment: Define "safe". Why is % unsafe?

Comment: "%" is not safe, if searched with "%" it will return all result

Answer (score 0):

(1) Special characters are a wider issue - you may need to convert the input:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580

(2) All characters may be allowed using the escape clause in sql server:
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE 
    column LIKE '%\@%' ESCAPE '\'